# Failed to upload log bucket, id '1' (delivery error code '1')

Tags: c, mongodb, kaa

The below is a data collection demo where by the structure of Kaa logs is defined by the chosen CT schema. This application will record the readings of the data I need and save them to the MongoDB database.

But with the upload bucket error , i think it failed..It continues logging.

```
[100%] Built target demo_client
Data collection demo started
Sampled SignalSTR:92  NodeId:Screws  Battery:5.93  CEL:4.65  WT:3.60  FirmwareVersion:Linux Welham V3.4  Status:On  Timestamp:1484555304
Sampled SignalSTR:94  NodeId:Screws  Battery:5.74  CEL:3.20  WT:1.77  FirmwareVersion:Linux Welham V3.4  Status:On  Timestamp:1484555309
Sampled SignalSTR:97  NodeId:Screws  Battery:5.17  CEL:2.20  WT:4.40  FirmwareVersion:Linux Welham V3.4  Status:On  Timestamp:1484555309
Sampled SignalSTR:98  NodeId:Screws  Battery:5.33  CEL:1.14  WT:4.47  FirmwareVersion:Linux Welham V3.4  Status:On  Timestamp:1484555309
Sampled SignalSTR:94  NodeId:Screws  Battery:5.69  CEL:4.78  WT:2.94  FirmwareVersion:Linux Welham V3.4  Status:On  Timestamp:1484555314
Sampled SignalSTR:96  NodeId:Screws  Battery:5.86  CEL:2.20  WT:4.62  FirmwareVersion:Linux Welham V3.4  Status:On  Timestamp:1484555319
Sampled SignalSTR:96  NodeId:Screws  Battery:5.81  CEL:3.42  WT:4.55  FirmwareVersion:Linux Welham V3.4  Status:On  Timestamp:1484555324
2017/01/16 8:28:49 [ERROR] [kaa_logging.c:803] (-6) - Failed to upload log bucket, id '1' (delivery error code '1')
```

What is this `Failed to upload log bucket, id '1' (delivery error code '1')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there problems with the code? It seems like kaa-node isnt the one that has problems because if he were to install kaa-node , he might have gotten other errors and failures instead of log delivery error. I think its your codes